# SQL Grouping based on Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running the following statement on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
DECLARE @Customer nvarchar(100);
SET     @Customer = 'Test';

SELECT  
    ProblemCategorization as 'Category'
    , COUNT(ProblemCategorization) as 'Count'
FROM 
    ININ_ISupport_S_Incident_Search2 (NULL) i  
WHERE 
    IncidentType IN ('Customer Support','Managed Services')
    AND i.Organization = @Customer
    AND i.IsResolved = 0
    AND i.Active = 1
    AND i.StateType = 'Open'
GROUP BY 
    i.ProblemCategorization
```

Results are as follows

```
Client Team 1
Client Team_IC Business Manager 3
Client Team_Interaction Attendant   1
Client Team_Interaction Client .NET 3
Client Team_Session Manager 1
```

I would like to total the counts from each one then group it into one results set as

```
Client Count
```

Comment: Are "Client Team", "Client Team_IC Business Manager", "Client Team_Interaction Client .NET" are all values in the ProblemCategorization  field?

Comment: yes they are the values in that field

Comment: Supposig that "Client" values in the example are just an alias and you are not expecting static Client values, there might be no acceptable solution for this. If you can construct a logic (such as "Client name is always the first and single word in ProblemCategorization field") or have Client name in another field (This is also does not make sense, because you would think this before me) you might parse string value according to the logic but no there appears no viable solution unless you have such a logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @Customer NVARCHAR(100);

SET @Customer = 'Test';

SELECT CASE
         WHEN i.ProblemCategorization LIKE '%client%' THEN 'client'
       END                          AS 'Category',
       Count(ProblemCategorization) AS 'client Count'
FROM   Inin_isupport_s_incident_search2 (NULL) i
WHERE  IncidentType IN ( 'Customer Support', 'Managed Services' )
       AND i.Organization = @Customer
       AND i.IsResolved = 0
       AND i.Active = 1
       AND i.StateType = 'Open'
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN i.ProblemCategorization LIKE '%client%' THEN 'client'
          END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [ROLLUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)?

Give this a try:

```
DECLARE @Customer nvarchar(100);
SET     @Customer = 'Test';
SELECT  ProblemCategorization as 'Category'
    , COUNT(ProblemCategorization) as 'Count'
FROM ININ_ISupport_S_Incident_Search2 (NULL) i  
WHERE IncidentType IN ('Customer Support','Managed Services')
AND     i.Organization = @Customer
AND     i.IsResolved = 0
AND     i.Active = 1
AND     i.StateType = 'Open'
Group By i.ProblemCategorization with rollup
```